# http-server to run app in angular2

Tags: angular

I have changed my app to run et on http-server. But after that I get onli 
Loading...
I seggest angular2 is not includes in project.

Here is a tree of my project:

```
client
   node_modules
   src
       app (all angular2 components)
       server.js
       tsconfig.json
       typings.d.ts
   angular-cli.json
   package.json
   tslint.json
```

So, in the package.json I have this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server src --cors -p 5000",
```

But after navigate to localhost:5000 I get "Loading " only.
What I do wrong here. Thanks

Comment: If you open up your developer tools (console), you'll probably see a message "GET..." (such and such page) not found." That message will be very useful. If it doesn't say that, it'll be some other error. One way or another, you need to look at the dev tools and find out what it's telling you. Post that error here if it doesn't tell you what you need to know to fix it.

Comment: There are no error not in dev console either in the message about GET...

Comment: Is there any error in your console? There must be something going wrong in your angular, console will give us an idea

Comment: No red lines in the network tab, no messages in the console, nothing?

Are you sure you're running in dev mode and/or that you are actually importing the bundle script in your index.html?